# Using SwiftUI, how to make multiple instances of AvAudioPlayer and access their properties?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I am trying to make a music app using SwiftUI which a user can set multiple times for different songs to play.

What is the best way to have multiple instances of AVAudioPlayer with each set to play at a specific time and have them accessible?

Please note that I will need to be able to access the isPlaying and the Stop() method for each instance of AVAudioPlayer.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement an instance of the AudioPlayer in a separate class and use it as an ObservableObject.
Inside the class you can have functions like play and pause.
You can pass as an initial argument the file name and create multiple instances of this player class.
A more detailed tutorial is here https://youtu.be/HNAhPXOhZnY. Sorry, it would be too much to write here.

Comment: Thanks. I have taken your SwiftUI - built a real world application using Core Data course on Udemy and loved it! I have been trying to get a drag and drop feature working on the ipad and iphone similar to the mac drag and drop we implemented. So far I have not had much success. Any helpful hints would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Also looking to buy your Combine Framework course. What parts do you cover in the course related to SwiftUI?